# How do I return a web page instead of writing a page in one line in FLASK pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, flask

This entire webpage is written in one line. I would like to write a page using 1000 lines instead of one long line. I would like to write some HTML in one file and display the code when I need it.

I am simply trying to print to lines such as

```
<p>line 1</p>
<p>line 2</p>
NOT <p>line 1</p><p>line 2</p>
```

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask
number = "7"
app = Flask(__name__)
redirect = "hi"
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
stuff = "<h2 style='text-align: center'>Welcome to Python Flask Web Server,   
your lucky number is: " + number + "!<h2>\n <p style='text-
align:center;'>Steve Wigmore Trained me!</p>\n 
<img style='margin: 0 auto; display: block; 
'src='cash-me-
outside-promo.jpg'</img>"
return stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is template engine such as Jinja2.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
number = "7"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', number=number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and then create a folder named `templates` in the same folder in which this script is present. Create your own template under `templates` and then render them in your app.

```
# templates/index.html
<h2 style='text-align: center'>Welcome to Python Flask Web Server, your lucky number is: {{ number }}!<h2>
<p style='text-align:center;'>Steve Wigmore Trained me! Cash me ousside How bou dat?</p>
<img style='margin: 0 auto; display: block;' src='https://www.maxim.com/.image/t_share/MTQ3MzM2ODA3NjExMTE0OTU4/cash-me-outside-promo.jpg'</img>
```

For more information about templates in Flask, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_templates.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use Jinja 2 Templates. Here are official [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/).